# adding a double to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I wrote an android app that solves quadratic equations and then is supposed to graph them. The library I am using requires the data sets to be in ArrayList form. However the loop I have to create the array involves adding a double to them which you cannot do with array lists. Here is the code:

```
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
QuadraticActivity c = new QuadraticActivity();


x=(c.xValueArr);
values=(c.yValueArr);

for (; c.xCurrent <= c.xEnd; c.xCurrent += c.xStep) {
    double yCurrent = (c.a)*Math.pow(c.xCurrent, 2) + (c.b)*c.xCurrent + (c.c);
    c. xValueArr .add ((c.xCurrent));
    c. yValueArr .add ((yCurrent));
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Note that you have a List of double arrays, not a list of doubles.

Comment: I suggest moving `line 3` to the first line and replacing the two `new ArrayList..` statements with the statements in lines 6 & 7. Your code should look like this:
`QuadtraticActivity c = new QuadraticActivity();
    List<Double> x = c.xValueArr;
    List<Double> values = c.yValueArr;` cause the `ArrayList`s that you created with new are just replaced in `lines 6 & 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code, `c.xValueArr` and `c.yValueArr` are of type, `double[]`. If so, then just change the first 7 lines of code to this:

```
QuadraticActivity c = new QuadraticActivity ();
ArrayList<Double> x = Arrays.asList (c.xValueArr);
ArrayList<Double> values = Arrays.asList (c.yValueArr);
```

*Note*: You're instantiating two new ArrayLists in `lines 1 and 2` but are replacing them in `lines 6 and 7`. Also, you'll have to add the new values inside the loop manually, as `x` and `values` don't point to the same arrays as `c`'s arrays. A better fix would be to declare and initialize `x` and `values` after the iteration, but since you didn't include a closing `}`, I'm assuming you need them in the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` should work fine with `Integer` or `Double` because they are as good as other object. Note that they must have the first letter capitalized.

You should also consider `Double.valueOf(double d)` which returns an object of Double for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Use the Double object instead of the double native type.

```
List<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but removed my upvote cause I reread the post, and realized @Owen isn't using the `ArrayList`s he initialized. Instead, he replaces them in `lines 6 & 7`. @Owen's question isn't too clear though, so AFAIK, you could still be right, though.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. I just answered his question about adding doubles to ArrayList and called it good.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a subclass of `Number`? It wraps a value in an object. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Try Double with a capital 'D'.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html